# Cannot present MoviePlayerView animation while a dismissMoviePlayerView animation is in progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller, movieplayer

I have an app that presents images and/or movies in sequence.  The problem is, I cannot dismiss one movie player and then present another. If I try, I get the message  "Warning: Attempt to present MPMoviePlayerViewController on MyViewController while a presentation is in progress!"  Unlike other animated present/dismiss methods, there is no completion handler, nor a non-animated version of present/dismiss.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
-(void) play
{
    [[window rootViewController] presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
    [[_player moviePlayer] play];
}

-(void) videoNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if([notification.name isEqualToString:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification])
    {
        [[window rootViewController] dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
        [_canvasManager showNextCanvas]; //this calls play on the next canvas
    }
}
```

Any thoughts/hints on how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at [dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated%3Acompletion:), I was able to create a completion handler by creating a subclass of MPMoviePlayerViewController and overriding -(void)viewDidDisappear.   viewDidDisappear gets called at the end of dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated.

```
@interface MyMoviePlayerViewController : MPMoviePlayerViewController
{
    void (^_viewDidDisappearCallback)(void);
}

- (void)setViewDidDisappearCallback:(void (^)(void))callback;

@end    

@implementation MyMoviePlayerViewController

- (id) initWithContentURL:videoPath
{
    self = [super initWithContentURL:videoPath];
    _viewDidDisappearCallback = nil;    
    return self;
}

- (void)setViewDidDisappearCallback:(void (^)(void))callback
{
    _viewDidDisappearCallback = [callback copy];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];    
    if(_viewDidDisappearCallback != nil)
        _viewDidDisappearCallback();
}

@end
```